# TYPO3 v10.1.0 won't install

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

I just wanted to install TYPO3 10.1.0, but the installation doesn't work.

At first, it throws an Server-500-error, without any php-errors.
After setting`'displayErrors' => true` I could see a detailed error message showing

`Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException`
`The file "/var/www/html/typo3/public/typo3/sysext/core/Configuration//Services.yaml" does not contain valid YAML: Unexpected characters near &quot;`

I opend that file, and removed all comments inside it, and reloaded the install.php, which resolved that error, but another error was thrown, this time in my php-output:

`NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class TYPO3\CMS\Core\Mail\FileSpool contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Symfony\Component\Mailer\Transport\TransportInterface::__toString) in /var/www/html/typo3/public/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Mail/FileSpool.php on line 38`

After I added the __toString():string function in FileSpool.php, I get another error

`NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of TYPO3\CMS\Core\Mail\Mailer::send(Symfony\Component\Mime\RawMessage $message, ?Symfony\Component\Mailer\SmtpEnvelope $envelope = NULL): void must be compatible with Symfony\Component\Mailer\MailerInterface::send(Symfony\Component\Mime\RawMessage $message, ?Symfony\Component\Mailer\Envelope $envelope = NULL): void in /var/www/html/typo3/public/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Mail/Mailer.php on line 38`

So, basically, the `core/classes/Mail` prevent me from installing TYPO3 10.1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known problem caused by changes in Symfony version 4.4 components and is solved in current master or version 10.2.0 (release scheduled for tomorrow, December 3rd) see [corresponding patch](https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/62354).

You currently have four options to circumvent this issue:

- wait for the new release of tomorrow
- use current master instead of 10.1
- apply the patch to your installation
- add the following lines to your composer.json

> ```
> "conflict": {
>   "symfony/config": "~4.4.0",
>   "symfony/console": "~4.4.0",
>   "symfony/dependency-injection": "~4.4.0",
>   "symfony/expression-language": "~4.4.0",
>   "symfony/finder": "~4.4.0",
>   "symfony/mailer": "~4.4.0",
>   "symfony/mime": "~4.4.0",
>   "symfony/property-access": "~4.4.0",
>   "symfony/property-info": "~4.4.0",
>   "symfony/routing": "~4.4.0",
>   "symfony/yaml": "~4.4.0"
> }
> ```

Comment: Since I just want to test it out, I used the current master-branch.